# Optimizing the query for CakePHP 3 ORM

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a query which looks like

```
$entity = $this->Products
  ->findById($id)
  ->contain( [ 'Categories',
  'Categories.Sizes',
  'ProductsPrices.Sizes' => function($q) { 
      return $q->select('Sizes.name');
    }
 ])->first();
```

In this case a `Product` belongTo a `Category` and in turn `Category` hasMany `Sizes` Similerly `Product`has many prices depending on it's size.

For example if a Product is available in 4 different sizes, then it will have 4 prices in the `ProductsPrices` table.

The query is returning the desired results, but problem is it is returning all the fields from each row. For example from `Categories` table i only need it's name. And from `Categories.Sizes` only id and name

Can I limit it to only fields which I need. I tried with `->select` at different levels but not working. For example `'ProductsPrices.Sizes'` I see only the Sizes query not the ProductsPrices one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more:

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html**

```
$entity = $this->Products
  ->findById($id)
  ->contain( [
   'Categories' => function($q){
      return $q->select(['name'])
        ->contain([
           'Sizes' => function($q) {
              return $q->select(['id','name']);
            }
        ]);
   },
   // -------------

 ])->first();
```